# Adjective, noun or what is the word few?

Tags: parts-of-speech

In the following sentence what is the word few:

> I thought about the question for a few moments?

Adjective, noun or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that sentence, it is an adjective.

Adj. 1. few - a quantifier that can be used with count nouns and is often preceded by `a'; a small but indefinite number; "a few weeks ago"; "a few more wagons than usual"